# Music recording

Tags: guitar

I have an acoustic treble with a fishman electric amplification system. I want to know how to record audio from the treble with my computer. What cables and what software would I need for that?

Comment: More than cables, probably an external sound card?  (I'm sure there is a similar question not so long ago, sure will find it, maybe you :)? )

Comment: What is an acoustic treble?

Comment: @Tom - it's a possibility, but it's not easy to give definitive answers using guesswork.

Comment: @Tim Is an Colombian instrument

Comment: If you search this stack for `ASIO`, you will probably find everything you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have an acoustic treble...

Ok. Forget about the pickup system, acoustic instruments are generally best recorded with a microphone. Even relatively cheap condenser microphones can easily give a more natural sound than the most fancy pickups.

The easiest option for mic is to use a portable recorder with USB-interface option, or a USB microphone. This way you skip needing a dedicated audio interface, so it's not even more of an investment.

Though an audio interface is certainly a good investment regardless, and then you can connect both microphones and electric signals.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what kind of instrument it is and what kind of output technology is available, you will need an interface that allows you to connect to a computer. The instrument, if it has no output cables, can always be recorded using a microphone, much like you would see an acoustic guitar *mic'd* up. Then you would connect the microphones audio cable into the input on the interface.

In order to record to a computer you have to have an audio interface that allows you to interface with the computer and your musical instrument. In your case using the ***fishman electric amplification*** you can mic the output there or run a mic directly into an audio interface that allows you to connect to a computer via, USB, USB-C, Thunderbolt, or Firewire, etc... Then play directly into the mic and record the misc output using the interface.

Most interfaces come with a driver for the operating system you would be using; ie **Windows, Mac OS...** You will need to download the driver and install it to use the interface with the operating system you are using.

Many audio interfaces come with recording software as a package. Some have templates for recording and will automatically set up the ***audio IO*** or in/out routing for you if you have a popular audio interface.

My suggestion would be to go to your local music store and talk to someone in the audio recording department and tell them what your needs are and look at some recording options they have for sale...

In short you will need a third party audio interface to connect your acoustic instrument and/or amp to that can interface with a computer via whatever connectivity technology your computer has available, ie; USB, Firewire, Thunderbolt, etc...